# Python 2 and 3 compatible string file writer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, stdout, python-unicode

I have created a python Context Manager that captures all output sys.stdout, such as with print(), and writes it to a file.

The problem is that I can't get this to work for both python 2.7 and 3.6.

The context manager internally uses

```
self.file_writer = open(self.log_file, 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

but when I run it in Python 2.7, then

```
print(u"a test string")
```

results in an error message:

```
write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Even though the string clearly is unicode.

If I change the file to

```
self.file_writer = open(self.log_file, 'wb')
```

then it works in Python 2.7, but not in 3.6.

What do I need to do to get it to work for any python version?

The following is an extract of the manager:

```
PATH_PREFIX = "some/path/"
class manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_file = os.path.join(PATH_PREFIX, 'log.txt')
    def __enter__(self):
        # create a file for logging
        self.log_file_stream = open(self.log_file, 'w', encoding='utf8')
        self.log_file_stream.__enter__()
        # redirect stdout to this file
        self.previous_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self.log_file_stream
        return self
    def __exit__(self, etype, value, exception_traceback):
        # stop redirecting stdout to the log file
        sys.stdout = self.previous_stdout
        # close the log file
        self.log_file_stream.__exit__()
```

Comment: I added a simplified version of the manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the other answers and learning that this is not possible with python's existing libraries, I wrote a context manager that replaces open(). It's a bit hacky, but it gets the job done.

It could probably be improved by explicitly checking for the python version instead of using hasattr(), but I didn't know about that when I wrote this:

```
class open_properly(object):
    """
    This is a file writer that doesn't complain about unicode/string mismatches.
    It works for both python 2.7 and 3+.
    """
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        super(open_properly, self).__init__()
        self.file_path = file_path
    def __enter__(self):
        self.file_writer = open(self.file_path, 'w', encoding='utf8')
        self.file_writer.__enter__()
        return self
    def write(self, s):
        if not isinstance(s, string_types):
            raise ValueError("the text to print must be a valid string type")
        # make sure it's unicode (important for python 2)
        if isinstance(s, str):
            if hasattr(s, 'decode'):
                s = s.decode('utf-8')
        # write unicode to file
        self.file_writer.write(s)
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self.file_writer.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

Answer (score 4):

`sys.stdout` is expected to be a byte stream in Python 2, but a Unicode stream in Python 3.  `print` for Python 2 encodes Unicode strings to a byte strings before writing to stdout, but you've overridden `sys.stdout` to be a Unicode stream in both Python 2 and Python 3.

When overriding `sys.stdout`, you need to provide a byte stream for Python 2, but a Unicode stream for Python 3.  You could use `sys.version_info.major` to decide which to support.